# How to save BBC iPlayer video downloads for viewing anytime?

Tags: video, video-editing, vlc, mp4

Videos downloaded via BBC iPlayer for later viewing on a Windows desktop PC appear to be standard MP4 files but in fact have two differences/problems:

- First, these MP4 files cannot be viewed using any of the usual applications such as VLC. Instead, they have to be viewed using a version of BBC iPlayer for the PC.
- Second, the files are time limited. Viewing is not permitted after a few days.

How can these two adaptations or alterations be undone/removed, so that the files can be

- (a) viewed with any standard video viewer, including VLC
- (b) (and more importantly) viewed two weeks or two months after downloading instead of being ruined by the time restriction?

Comment: You *may* be looking for software that does this, but you are not saying so. That makes this question off-topic for this site. Can you [edit] it to make it a clear software request?

Comment: I don't know of any existing software that would fix the problem(s). I wonder why it is that the downloads (which are saved as mp4 files - i.e. they have the .mp4 file extension) will not play via VLC. They seem to be recognised/accepted by VLC and progress as usual... but no images or sound appears.

Comment: Well, this site is not for "why does this happen" or "how to make it *not* happen" – but for recommendations of software meeting specific requirements. A hint, though: [Digital restriction management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_rights_management)

Answer (score 0):

You could give [youtube-dl](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#readme) a try.  It is a free, FOSS, cross platform, python library *that is also available as a Windows executable for* which allows video and audio downloads from a multitude of sites, including the BBC. Just tried pulling in an episode of Click and it is playing fine through VLC.

Once you have the file, you can run it through [FFMPEG](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) to convert format which should strip any expiry dates out.